# How can I set the end dragging velocity of a UICollectionView with custom flow layout?

Tags: cocoa-touch, uiscrollview, ios7, uicollectionview

I'm working on a UICollectionView with a custom flow layout subclass which, among other things, does some custom "paging". Everything's fine but for the fact that depending on how I drag, when I release and after `- (CGPoint)targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset:(CGPoint)proposedContentOffset withScrollingVelocity:(CGPoint)velocity` gets called, the collection view (or some part of the `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` which I did not yet know I need to override) is controlling the velocity with which the animation of an item snapping happens.

- That is, if I slightly offset an item from the center of the
  collection view qnd release, it snaps back to its position pretty
  quickly (desired).
- But If I drag the item, say, half way past the collection view's
  frame and/or change swiping directions while still dragging and then
  release, the "snap" animation takes too long (not desired: I'd like the velocity to adjust so that the end drag animation takes the same amount of time always, regardless of distance).

I tried modifying the `decelerationRate` of the collection view but it doesn't seem to do anything. And I'm thinking of writing my own animation block in one of the collection view delegate methods, but I'm wondering if there is a different way (perhaps from within the flow layout subclass?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, actually setting `self.collectionView.decelerationRate = 0.;` seems to work for now. It at least does not decelerate the scrolling and so it looks like constant velocity which is not exactly what I wanted but feels almost right.

Comment: Works like a charm! Since the left and right insets were larger than the spacing between cells deceleration was faster when getting to the end and beginning of the collection.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to achieve collection view cell paging! This + targetContentOffsetForProposedContentOffset :)